# Laravel 5.4 Broadcast : Pusher->Error->WebSocketError

Tags: pusher, laravel-5.4, laravel-echo

I just began to use Broadcasting with Pusher and Echo. My problem is that I'm getting an error and I can't find how to resolve it. The error message look pretty straigthfoward, but I have no idea where I should head to get rid of it.

My laravel is an upgrade from Laravel 5.3. I uncommented the `App/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider::class into config.php`.
I created an event and set the Private channel.`return new PrivateChannel('dealer.'$this->client->dealer_id);`
I added the new channel into `routes/channels.php`

```
Broadcast::channel('dealer.{dealerId}', function ($user, $dealerId) {
    return (int) $user->dealer_id === (int) $dealerId;
});
```

I added this to bootstrap.js

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'my-secrect-key'
});
```

I also added everything to the .env file. Finally, I added the channel to the script at the end of the applayout.blade.php

```
Echo.private(`dealer.1`)
    .listen('NewClient', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

When I load the page, this is the error I got from the console:

```
Pusher : Error : {
    "type":"WebSocketError",
    "error":{
        "type":"PusherError",
        "data":{
            "code":null,
            "message":"Auth value for subscription to private-dealer.1 is invalid: should be of format 'key:signature'"
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading Laravel 5.3 to 5.4 you should make changes in your .env file

Change From:

```
PUSHER_KEY
PUSHER_SECRET
```

to

```
PUSHER_APP_KEY
PUSHER_APP_SECRET
```

Someone answered it on Laracast. [Link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-broadcast-pusher-error-websocketerror)

Comment: Funny fact, the link lead to my question on laracast

Comment: Ooppsss!! Sorry, Actually, I didn't check who posted it. :D I had an issue with the clustering on Pusher at that time I came across it. :)

Comment: Its fine, people who will cone there will see the answer